# Can iwconfig performance metrics be obtained with iw?

Tags: wifi, iw

I understand `iwconfig` is deprecated and I should use `iw` instead.

`iwconfig` returns some useful wifi performance KPIs:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"mynetwork"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.805 GHz  Access Point: [mac redacted]
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:289  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

`iw dev wlan0 link` shows only the following KPIs:

```
Connected to [mac redacted] (on wlan0)
        SSID: mynetwork
        freq: 5805
        RX: 26639983 bytes (233840 packets)
        TX: 179162612 bytes (367250 packets)
        signal: -74 dBm
        rx bitrate: 234.0 MBit/s
        tx bitrate: 87.7 MBit/s

        bss flags:
        dtim period:    2
        beacon int:     100
```

`iw dev wlan0 info` only shows static hardware & configuration information about the connected network, there's no performance KPIs.

Is there a way to get the `Rx invalid nwid`, `Rx invalid crypt`, `Rx invalid frag`, `Tx excessive retries`, `Invalid misc`, or `Missed beacon` counters with `iw`?

If `iw` is not supposed to provide this information, is there a non-deprecated tool which *does* provide it?